# Python pytest cases for async and await method

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, pytest, aiohttp

I am trying to write pytest for the following async, await methods but I am getting nowhere.

```
   class UserDb(object):
    async def add_user_info(self,userInfo):
      return await self.post_route(route='users',json=userInfo)

    async def post_route(self,route=None,json=None,params=None):
      uri = self.uri + route if route else self.uri      
      async with self.client.post(uri,json=json,params=params) as resp:            
      assert resp.status == 200
      return await resp.json()
```

Can someone help me with this? TIA

Comment: are you using aiohttp?

Comment: @Juggernaut :  yes, I am using aiohttp.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`pip install pytest-aiohttp`, then create a fixture like this

```
from pytest import fixture

def make_app():
    app = Application()
    # Config your app here
    return app

@fixture
def test_fixture(loop, test_client):
    """Test fixture to be used in test cases"""
    app = make_app()
    return loop.run_until_complete(test_client(app))
```

Now write your tests

```
f = test_fixture

async def test_add_user_info(f):
    resp = await f.get('/')
    assert resp.status == 200
    assert await resp.json() == {'some_key': 'some_value'}
```

Also I noticed your `add_user_info` coroutine isn't returning anything.
More info is [here](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/testing.html#pytest)

Comment: I am a beginner to pytest. can you give me more information about configuring the app and test fixtures?

Comment: configuration is optional. it consist of adding middle-wares like session management or db configuration management. Simply create your test cases and use `test_fixture` as an argument for you testcase. like the one I put in the answer. and run `py.test test_module.py` in your terminal.

Comment: got it. Thank you so much :)