# Python coverage for async methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I use aiohttp, pytest and pytest-cov to get coverage of my code. I want to get better coverage< but now I am a little bit stuck, because event simple code does not show 100% cov. For example this piece of code:

```
@session_decorator()
async def healthcheck(session, request):
    await session.scalar("select pg_is_in_recovery();")
    return web.json_response({"status": "ok"})
```

in coverage report it shows that line with return is not covered.

I have read this link [Code coverage for async methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15603813/code-coverage-for-async-methods). But this is for C# and I can not understand:

> This can happen most commonly if the operation you're awaiting is
> completed before it's awaited.

My code to run tests:

```
python3.9 -m pytest -vv --cov --cov-report xml --cov-report term-missing
```

My test for code above

```
async def test_healthz_page(test_client):
    response = await test_client.get("/healthz")
    assert response.status == HTTPStatus.OK
```

Comment: How did your unittest invoke the `healthcheck` function?  You may need to adapt your test case methods such that they execute as intended, please take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23033939/how-to-test-python-3-4-asyncio-code) on how this may be done.

Comment: added in the post

Comment: You will need to mark your test correctly with pytest, see [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49936724/async-fixtures-with-pytest) and [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45944158/python-pytest-cases-for-async-and-await-method) and [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65652242/testing-asyncio-with-pytest-how-to-test-a-try-except-block-by-mocking-the-event) for examples.

Comment: Pytest doesn't have built-in support for async tests. What plugin do you use for that, `pytest-asyncio` or something else?

Comment: ```
platform darwin -- Python 3.9.2, pytest-6.2.4, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: configfile: pytest.ini, testpaths: tests
plugins: Faker-8.9.1, cov-2.12.1, env-0.6.2, anyio-3.2.1, aiohttp-0.3.0
collected 53 items         
```

Comment: Tried to install pytest-asyncio it does not work at all)
so it seems some plugin and this functionality. I mean ability to run async tests. Maybe anyio?

Comment: Even with asyncio properly setup I have the same issue; the `return` like is never shown as covered even if it is.

Comment: To clarify: the code after the first `await` is never shown as covered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue when testing FastAPI code using asyncio. The fix is to create or edit a `.coveragerc` at the root of your project with the following content:

```ini
[run]
concurrency = gevent
```

If you use a `pyproject.toml` you can also include this section in that file instead:

```ini
[tool.coverage.run]
concurrency = ["gevent"]
```

In addition, you have to `pip install gevent`. If using Poetry, run `poetry add --group dev gevent`.

If the above doesn’t work, try using `concurrency = thread,gevent` instead (see [this comment](https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/issues/1082#issuecomment-979462293). Note it says to use `--concurrency` but this option is not available when you use `pytest-cov`; you must use `.coveragerc`).