# Pytest term missing like stuck by fixture

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, pytest, fastapi, pytest-cov

I have a FastAPI application, I use SQLAlchemy 2.0 in async mode to connect to my postgres database.

This is my endpoint FastAPI:

```py
@router.get("", response_model=HelloResponse)
async def get_hello(
    current_user: UserResponse = Security(
        get_current_active_user,
        scopes=[Scoper.admin, Scoper.staff],
    ),
    db=Depends(get_session),
):
    hello = await HelloManager(db).get(id=1)
    if hello.foo == "bar":
        return hello
    return await HelloManager(db).get(id=2)
```

My test : test_hello.py

```py
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_hello_with_mocked_security(async_client: AsyncClient):
    app.dependency_overrides[get_current_user] = mock_get_current_user

    response = await async_client.get("/api/hello", headers=headers_hocked_token)

    assert response.status_code == 200
    data = response.json()
    assert data["id"] == 2
    assert data["name"] = "Hello2 !!"
```

The test passed correctly but Coverage says that these 3 lines (after `hello = await HelloManager(db).get(id=1)` ) are not tested:

```py
if hello.foo == "bar":
        return hello
    return await HelloManager(db).get(id=2)
```

I have the same situation in several places: the use of managers and everything that goes with it is said to be untested, but the tests pass with the right feedback.

Here's my conftest.py, with the fixtures. I think the problem must be here, I must have done something wrong, because to tell you the truth I had a hard time overriding my `db=Depends(get_session),`...

```py
from typing import AsyncIterator
from my_app.db.database import get_session
from httpx import AsyncClient
import pytest
from my_app.db.models.base_model import BaseModelORM
from my_app.settings import settings
from sqlalchemy import text
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession, create_async_engine, async_sessionmaker
from my_app.main import app

from my_app.settings import get_settings as original_get_settings


@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
async def init_database() -> None:
    """
    Initialize the database before running the tests.
    """

    engine = create_async_engine(
        settings.sqlalchemy_database_uri_async or "",
        echo=False,
    )
    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(BaseModelORM.metadata.drop_all)
        await conn.run_sync(BaseModelORM.metadata.create_all)

@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
async def async_engine():
    engine = create_async_engine(
        settings.sqlalchemy_database_uri_async,  # type: ignore
        echo=False,
    )
    return engine


@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def TestingSessionLocalAsync(async_engine):
    return async_sessionmaker(
        async_engine,
        class_=AsyncSession,
        expire_on_commit=False,
    )


@pytest.fixture(scope="function", autouse=True)
async def db(async_engine, TestingSessionLocalAsync) -> AsyncIterator[AsyncSession]:
    async with async_engine.connect() as conn:
        async_session = TestingSessionLocalAsync()

        yield async_session

    await async_session.close()
    await conn.close()


@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def get_settings():
    settings.fapi_mode = "TESTING"
    settings.sqlalchemy_database_uri_async = (
        f"postgresql+asyncpg://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/test_myapp"
    )
    return settings



@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def override_get_db(db: AsyncSession):
    async def _override_get_db():
        yield db

    return _override_get_db


@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
async def async_client(override_get_db, get_settings):
    app.dependency_overrides[get_session] = override_get_db
    app.dependency_overrides[original_get_settings] = get_settings
    async with AsyncClient(app=app, base_url="http://test.test") as ac:
        yield ac
```

I hope someone can help me :)

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68826941/python-coverage-for-async-methods?

Comment: Wow it works, I'm going to search a little more on my side to understand better, thank you very much.